# GPU-Z Temperature Sensor Questions

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, temperature, amd-radeon

I am going to make this as generic as possible so to help future searches for a concrete answer. I spent over an hour searching google and forums attempting to find an answer.

Here is a capture of my GPU-Z sensor readout:
[image]

What/where are the different sensors that give these different temperature readings?

- **GPU Temperature**
- **GPU Temp. #1**
- **GPU Temp. #2**
- **GPU Temp. #3**
- **VRM Temperature #1**
- **VRM Temperature #2**

I know with CPUs there is the core and socket temperatures, is that the case with GPUs as well?

Thanks!

Comment: They are on the card.  What is your actual problem your trying to solve?

Comment: GPU Temp obviously refers to the GPU processor itself, the main processing chip. There is often a Ram sencor somewhere. VRMs are the voltage regulators, basically the layer of power curcuits. Using any GPU torture tool say Furmark, you could do what is called an "artifacts testing" which races through ram over and over again, and probably locate which one represents ram (or close to ram). There is often an "ambient" which just hangs out in the heat of the whole board.

Comment: Search google, the problem with that is you have an I/O chip that is connected to a bunch of sencors. Much like your car has sencors on various components that feed to a computer. A All-for-1 software (excellent that is is) Is just reading numbers out of a register and usually putting them in the correct places, but not always :-) They probably are temps, they are mostly standardised, but some of them might not even be connected. A bit of user viewing it and having an idea what it refers to, if it changes even, is the only guarentee. Different manufactures, different ways.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am aware the sensors are on the card. There is no real "problem" per se; just curious to which of the 6 sensors would be the best one to monitor temps. For instance, as I mentioned in the OP, I monitor the Core Temp on my CPU more closely than the Socket Temp.

Comment: It would be the three sensors `GPU Temp#1`, `GPU Temp #2`, `GPU Temp #3`